# What is the exact PostgreSQL driver used by PyQt6?

Tags: python, driver, pyqt6

How can I determine the exact PostgreSQL driver used by PyQt6? QPSQL is a Qt thingy for which there is no documentation as to configuration options, so I'm guessing it's just a wrapper for a real driver.

There is no such thing as a "PostgreSQL Driver", as shown in the QSqlDatabase doc.

Postgres version 12 docs lists the following "external projects" as possible drivers: DBD::Pg, JDBC, libpqxx, node-postgres, Npgsql, pgtcl, pgtclng, pq, psqlODBC, psycopg. There are also two native drivers: libpq, ECPG.

Though not listed in the version 12 docs, there are several variations of ODBC, divided into single-tier and multi-tier types.

A Postgres doc states that psqlODBC is the "official PostgreSQL ODBC driver", but that doesn't mean that PyQt6 is using it.

Possibly Qt won't commit to a specific driver because they may want to change driver implementation without notice. Nevertheless, I'd like to know what I have so I can tweak its options. Even better, I'd like to use a different driver if I don't like the one Qt provides. Qt has a section, "Compile Qt with a specific driver"; that should not be necessary for a PyQt6 programmer, and it is not clear whether such a compiled thing would find its way into PyQt6 with the static method, registerSqlDriver(). The QSqlDriver doc has a bunch of enums used with the hasFeature() method; this is useful, but it's not the same as manipulating driver parameters. The JDBC driver has a whole raft of options which are enumerated in the Postgres docs; I'd like to be able to retrieve a similar list for whatever driver Qt implements.

Any help, please.

Comment: The standard supported specifics are on https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/sql-driver.html#qpsql but it's not clear what you mean by "[compiling a specific driver] should not be necessary for a PyQt6 programmer".

Comment: @musicamante Thank you for your response. I am familiar with that link. It contains no information whatsoever about the specific driver provided by Qt. My comment about the PyQt6 programmer means that PyQt6 is supposed to be a wrapper around Qt6 such that the python programmer can use all the features of Qt6 without being a C++ nerd. If there are alternate postgres drivers avilable, they should be documented in PyQt6, not just in Qt, and should include all available programmable options. Such documentation appears in neither PyQt6 nor Qt. Not even the default driver is documented.

Comment: There are no "other" drivers available: each Sql type has just one driver, Qt interfaces with it, and PyQt along with Qt. Qt allows creating your own drivers if you want special behavior, a specific driver, a custom one, or any other reason. Qt is shipped with binary drivers that are built by Qt, PyQt just uses it and won't (nor could) anything different, that's why the documentation is usually poor: except for a few specific situations, the documentation would be exactly the same. If you want to extend PyQt beyond the existing Qt capabilities, you can only do it on the Qt side.

Comment: @musicamante Does that mean that Qt ships a home-brew postgres driver? It's not one of those listed in the postgres docs, like psycopg or psqlODBC? If so, then that answers my question.

Answer (score 1):

Qt uses `libpq` driver for `qsqlpsql` plugin.

Comment: Thank you. Could you tell me how you determined this? I could not find any Qt docs on this question. Did you have to rummage around Qt source code?

Comment: I compiled Qt and plugins. You can see libpq calls in sources https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/plugins/sqldrivers/psql/qsql_psql.cpp?h=5.12